# Need of describing the term acceleration

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, acceleration, velocity

What is the need of acceleration when we have velocity
As I think velocity as 1m/s means 1m covered in 1s and 1m/s^2 means 1m covered in 1s per 1s this statement creates confusion when it comes to acceleration hence please tell the real purpose of acceleration?

Comment: *1m/s^2 means 1m covered in 1s per 1s.* No, you don’t yet understand acceleration. It tells you how fast the velocity is changing. What you wrote doesn’t make sense.

Comment: "What is the real purpose of acceleration" is a metaphysical question -- why do we need anything in the universe?   The reason that we need to handle it in physical problems is because if you have a finite force, and a finite mass, then you're going to have a finite acceleration.  You can't just instantaneously impose changes in velocity on a mass: that leads to singularities (or infinities, same thing).

Comment: You can have an idea with form into a relevant question.The values will solve the confusion. Pursuit https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/20800/acceleration-value-disparity?rq=1 That is the better way for understanding

Answer (score 2):

Speed is the rate of change of distance with respect to time. 1 m/s means every second the distance increases by 1 meter.

Acceleration is the rate of change of speed with respect to time. 1 m/s/s means every second the speed increases by 1 meter per second.

You can plug those definitions to any computer program and never have to use calculus to get your approximate results to any problem.

Comment: But in acceleration, second square is confusing me

Comment: 1m/s/s = 1m/s^2. It's fractional division.

Comment: But imagining such thing is too difficult

Comment: Okay well, you definitely can tell a difference between a car that takes 5s to get to 100 km/h speed and a car that takes 20s to do the same, right?

Comment: Yes I can tell the difference

Answer (score 0):

$\rm acceleration = \dfrac{\text{change in velocity}\,(\rm m\, s^{-1})}{\text{time taken for change}\,(\rm s)}$

The units of acceleration are  $\dfrac{\rm m\, s^{-1}}{\rm s}= \rm m\, s^{-1} \times s^{-1}=m\,s^{-2}$.

Acceleration is a measure how much velocity changes with time in the same way that velocity is a measure of how much displacement changes with time.

You probably have no problem with the units of velocity because they are $\dfrac{\rm m}{\rm s} = \rm m\,s^{-1}$ and the numerator is just a single unit.

If the unit of velocity was the $\rm "james"$ then the unit os acceleration would be $\rm james\,s^{-1}$